# Rails 3.2.1 - cannot parse Cookie header: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've updated the rails gem to version 3.2.1 and I created a dummy test application, but when execute I get this error:

```
NoMethodError
cannot parse Cookie header: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

Anyone know help me?

Comment: The error message says the method 'size' has been called on a nil object. If you want help, you should post the stacktrace of the error, and the part of your code where the error occurred

Comment: It's a new application, don't have any code. I just created the WelcomeController, delete public/index.html and visit http://localhost:3000/.

The console log: http://pastebin.com/BA6TcSei

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with rack. I was able to fix it by pointing my Gemfile to master for the time being.

```
gem 'rack', git: 'git://github.com/rack/rack.git'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing your cookies:
http://www.aboutcookies.org/Default.aspx?page=2

Comment: But I assume one can't constantly ask clients to clear their cookies, anyone know if this will get fixed?

Answer (score 1):

For historical purposes, anyone researching this issue should know that this bug has been fixed as of 2012-08-10.

Updating to Rack 1.4.2 or 1.5.0 or newer should fix this issue.

https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/386#issuecomment-7660902

Answer (score 0):

Also had this problem.  It was caused by a comma in the value of a cookie being sent in the request headers.  The cookie with the bad value was set by a different site running on the same domain (different sub-domain).  Removing the bad cookie with the comma fixed the problem.