# undefined method `size' for #<ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x007fa415c12670>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, cookies

i am migrating an application from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1, most of it is done but there is a issue, when the session get expired and i reload the page instead of redirecting me to login page i am getting a error

**undefined method `size' for ActionDispatch::Cookies::CookieJar:0x007fa415c12670>**

here is the code where i am getting the error

```
def access_denied
  respond_to do |accepts|
    accepts.html do
      test_location
      if cookies.size==0 && request.host == "somedomain.com"
        redirect_to "/cookies_disabled.html"
      else
        redirect_to new_session_url
      end
    end
    accepts.js do
      render :text => "window.location.href = '#{new_session_url}';"
    end
  end
  false
end
```

any help will be appriciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

appears to be a repost of this 
[Rails 3.2.1 - cannot parse Cookie header: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054604/rails-3-2-1-cannot-parse-cookie-header-undefined-method-size-for-nilnilcla)

try updating your rack gem.

Comment: i did check this post, but i am not using rack gem

Answer (score 0):

There is no `size` method apparently.

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActionDispatch/Cookies/CookieJar

`cookies.to_json.size` works nicely